# How to differentiate tabs and spaces on GitHub diff checker?

Tags: github

As a Python developer, spacing is extremely important.

Is it possible to differentiate tabs/spaces in GitHub pull request diffs? (I realize that the true solution is probably to have a linter run before allowing remote push, but I thought this would be a nice fallback.)